# Word displayed reversed when typing in the Entry when adding TextTransform="Uppercase" attribute

Tags: .net, maui

I am developing a mobile application with dotnet maui (Only Android platform.).

With dotnet 6 I have no problem with the Entry control

But with dotnet 7 I have a serious problem with the Entry control my problem is the following:

If I add TextTransform="Uppercase" attribute and when I type a word in the entry control the entered word is displayed reversed for example if I type problem I have MELBORP. idem with maui community toolkit MaskedBehavior i have the same issue.

I don't know what is the problem.
Any Help please

I dont understant why , and i did'nt do any thing

Comment: Please [edit] your question.  "Dotnet Develpper" is not a descriptive title and has nothing to do with the problem you are actually having.  Please read [ask] for guidance on writing a good question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the case as you said.

And there is a known issue about this problem, you can follow up here: [Entry with TextTransform=Uppercase](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11313).

Thanks for your support and feedback.